# BCM4313 partially working on Toshiba Satellite R630 (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: wireless, broadcom

New to Ubuntu.
During installation, the computer identified the wifi card and asked me to connect to the network. I did. After the first restart the wifi was working and I could see networks and connect to them. After the second restart the wireless has VANISHED. Still, the Broadcom STA drivers are enabled in system settings/additional drivers. Tried to restart 5 more times- no effect.
I have studied very many topics on askubuntu but none of them work.

Comment: Which options have you actually found and tried? What does `ifconfig -a` show? What does `lspci -nn` show? etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am also using BCM4313 on 12.10, but on IdeaPad. There are couple possible issues, so lets start with:

BCM4313 is not a great wifi card and linux support is also not perfect. However, it is  fine for day to day use and you can get it running on linux without much work.

In my case I have installed a module for the wifi using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you can see other WIFI networks, but not your one it might be because BCM4313 doesn't support high radio channels. In my case, I had to adjust my router from channel 13 to channel 8 to get it working fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have an error while installing bcmwl-kernel-source:

Comment: wl module does not exist